# Breaking command output into new lines instead of refreshing the same line

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, sed, tee

I'm trying to write a script that involves [SnapRAID](https://www.snapraid.it/), where the progress output of `snapraid sync` is timestamped and logged to both a file and stdout. The issue I am facing is that `snapraid sync` outputs its progress onto a single line that it refreshes each second. This means that when running it in a script, the only output you're left with is something like `100% completed, 7737 MB accessed in 0:00`. You cannot look back at how the command ran.

By using `ts`, `sed` and `tee`, I am partially able to achieve my goals:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="/tmp/snapRAID.log"

exec 1>> >(ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]') 2>&1

snapraid sync | sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' | tee >(ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" >> $LOG_FILE)
```

This results in the following output to `stdout` and `/tmp/snapRAID.log` (amongst the rest of the output of `snapraid sync`):

```
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 0%, 0 MB
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 5%, 552 MB
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 12%, 1332 MB
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 17%, 1942 MB
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 21%, 2311 MB
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 27%, 3044 MB, 622 MB/s, 1188 stripe/s, CPU 14%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 35%, 3836 MB, 656 MB/s, 1253 stripe/s, CPU 14%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 42%, 4612 MB, 676 MB/s, 1306 stripe/s, CPU 15%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 49%, 5005 MB, 636 MB/s, 1334 stripe/s, CPU 15%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 58%, 5493 MB, 617 MB/s, 1400 stripe/s, CPU 16%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 67%, 5987 MB, 581 MB/s, 1449 stripe/s, CPU 16%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 75%, 6415 MB, 564 MB/s, 1470 stripe/s, CPU 16%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 80%, 6694 MB, 536 MB/s, 1429 stripe/s, CPU 15%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 84%, 6916 MB, 507 MB/s, 1376 stripe/s, CPU 15%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 92%, 7314 MB, 498 MB/s, 1388 stripe/s, CPU 15%, 0:00 ETA
[2023-04-23 16:24:51] 97%, 7574 MB, 433 MB/s, 1268 stripe/s, CPU 13%, 0:00 ETA
```

The issue is that this output is not live - the entire output of `snapraid sync` appears in stdout and the logfile only once it has finished running. This remains the same if I remove the `tee` element and just have it output to `stdout`. This is not helpful to me if I want to look at how `snapraid sync` is progressing mid-run. This test instance completes its sync in seconds, but the machine I want to be running this on can take hours, and I want to be able to checkup on the progress of the command mid-run, while also being able to look back at a run that happened previously and view timestamps.

I have tried some of the following ideas, with no success:

```
unbuffer snapraid sync | sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' | tee >(ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" >> $LOG_FILE)

snapraid sync | sed -u -e 's/\r/\n/g' | tee >(ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" >> $LOG_FILE)
```

Does anyone know how I might go about making this timestamped new-line output happen live?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the following before both both the sync and the sed command: `stdbuf -o0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` buffers its output since it's not going to a tty. Some `sed` implementations support a `-u` option to disable that buffering, or you can use `stdbuf`, with `sed` or with `tr` that would be more appropriate especially considering that neither `\r` nor `\n` are standard there in `sed`.

```
snapraid sync |
  stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' |
  ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' |
  tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
```

If `snapraid` also buffers its output when not going to a terminal, you  can try that same `stdbuf` trick there, though you'd likely want `stdbuf -o0` (no buffering) as opposed to `stdbuf -oL` (line-based buffering) there:

```
stdbuf -o0 snapraid sync |
  stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' |
  ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' |
  tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
```

In any case, `stdbuf` is not a standard command either, but where available should be preferable over `unbuffer` which is an `expect` script that  uses a pseudo-tty to try and convince applications not to buffer but has been known to mangle output.

`-u` is not a standard option to `sed` either.

Note that many `sed` implementations also read one line in advance so as to be able to know when the `$` address matches which means you get a one line delay on output there even when it goes to a terminal device.

`ts` is a `perl` script that does `$| = 1` to explicitly disable buffering. In my tests, GNU `tee` at least doesn't buffer its output even if none of the destination files nor stdout are terminal devices.

BTW, writing to files with fixed names in world-writable directories such as `/tmp` is bad practice from a security standpoint and should be avoided. Either use `mktemp` to be guaranteed you get your own temp file there, or write the file to a directory of yours where nobody else can plant malicious symlinks for instance.

Comment: Many thanks Stéphane. Your first suggestion works perfectly. I'll take your comments around using `/tmp` in this way into consideration when putting this into my 'production' machine.